# How do I create a server setup for two Rails apps with different Ruby versions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a large instance of EC2. I have a application using Rails 4.0 and Ruby 2.0, running using Unicorn.

I want to deploy another, very small, application using Rails 4.0.1 and Ruby 2.1 on the instance.

Can I use Unicorn for both apps? If not, can I use Nginx + Unicorn for both? What would be appropriate approach for this?

I wanted to use Nginx+passenger but that wont support different Ruby versions.

This is a sample Nginx configuration, which doesn't work because both applications need different Ruby versions:

```
http {
  passenger_root /home/prasad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/passenger-3.0.18;
  passenger_ruby /home/prasad/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p286/ruby;
  ...
  server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  dev.app1; #uses ruby 1.9.3
    passenger_enabled on;
    root   /home/prasad/projects/app1/public;
    rails_env development;
  }

  server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  dev.app2; #uses ruby 2.0
    passenger_enabled on;
    root   /home/prasad/projects/app2/public;
    rails_env development;
  }
  ...
```

I am looking for a solution where I can run multiple applications with different stacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to upgrade to v4 or greater of Passenger, so that you can configure the Ruby version per application.

Essentially, in addition to the HTTP block where you have "passenger_ruby" globally configured in your example, you can specify a separate Ruby per server :

```
server {
  # This Rails web app will use Ruby 1.9.3, as installed by RVM
  passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3/ruby;
  ...
}
```

See the full documentation at : 
http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#PassengerRuby